# Include several Plotly with pdf() in R

Tags: r, pdf, plotly

I am trying to include several `plotly` plots in a pdf. I tried `plotly::renderPlotly` and `print` around the objects without success. Is there a way to do it using the `pdf()` command and not a `RMarkdown` ?

The `plotly` graphs never render. How to include them in the document ?

```
pdf("example.pdf")
plot(1:2)
plotly::plot_ly(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
dev.off()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.